# Safest way to escape Mysql's like in nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sails.js, rawsql

I'm using sails, but for a particular query I have to use the raw query. In this way, I don't know how to escape the data that I will have to insert inside the like in the query.
What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Could you give us a code example and explain what goes wrong or what you extect to go wrong?